# Logic Apps SFTP - SSH Connection Issue

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In Logic Apps, when I try to establish a connection to an SFTP server using SFTP - SSH connector, I get the error-

> Please check your account info and/or permissions and try again.
>   Details: Server response does not contain SSH protocol identification

Using the same credentials, I am able to connect through FileZilla.
What could be the cause/s of this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: This issue may caused by the version of nuget or module which used in the backend of logic app SFTP - SSH connector.

Comment: @HuryShen Thank you for the response! I was using the SFTP - SSH connector to connect to 2 SFTP servers with the same version. One works and the other does not. Anywhere else you can suggest to look into?

Answer (score 0):

Exact same problem here.

I was able to connect to the server in a previous version of the LogicApp, but now, i have the same error with the same behaviour (able to connect via FileZilla).

**EDIT:**
 The temporary solution is to change the LogicApp in another region. May be link to a blacklisted IP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Same here.

Please check your account info and/or permissions and try again. Details: BadGateway More diagnostic information: x-ms-client-request-id is '2EBE210A-4A57-4BF6-A239-899ADA252200'.

We could not get any SFTP-SSH connector to work in the Australia East region.
We switched the logic app to the Australia SouthEast region and created the connection there and it was all good.

Comment: did you use a classic logicapp or new workflow/docker style? I've tried mutliple regions, nothing seems to work

Comment: classic this was developed before the new workflow docker style existed