# Logic apps connector gets private IP instead of public IP

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

We have in our tenant a few Logic Apps which are scheduled to run at specific time.
We are working with a partner and we are uploading files to their SFTP server. Now they are moving to Azure blob storage and they provided us the sftp credentials to their blob `xx.blob.core.windows.net`

Previously they gave us an STFP account ( the server was not from Azure or was not Azure blob storage), and we could upload the necessary files using Logic Apps; they added our connector IP's to their whitelist and everything was working fine.

Now our partner are moving in the cloud and created a blob account in the same Azure location as our Azure apps location which in this case is West Europe, when I try to change the connector settings in order to be able to connect to their blob ( another tenant) they are seeing in the logs the IP of our Logic app  as a private IP.

[image]

I then tried to simulate this from another tenant and it's indeed using a private IP.

What I tested is probably what they did from the network setting in the storage account **Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses** whitelisted the connector IP addresses which are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/common/outbound-ip-addresses
Then I whitelist my external IP and I could access the blob from my PC but the connector won't do it. When I change the network settings to **Enabled from all networks** I am perfectly able to connect from the Logic App. I also tried to create the storage in another location and then in the logs I see the public IP of the connector and I am able to connect from the logic app.

Which solutions are there to access their blob? Moving their blob to another location is not an option and I also would prefer to keep our logic apps in the same region.

Comment: it's the same issue like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61197939/logic-apps-sftp-ssh-connection-issue?rq=2

Comment: Is your logic app is connected to virtual network or private network?

Comment: @RithwikBojja virtual

Comment: If it is virtual you should try it from Virtual machine which is connected to that VN

Answer (score 0):

> Logic apps connector gets private IP instead of public IP

AFAIK, the main reason for this that as you said connected it to Virtual Network. Because of this you will get Ip's as Private.

You need to make the storage account in West Europe to use the Virtual network. Then only you will be able to access it.

[image]

If you remove vnet integration to your logic app then the Ips will be back to public.